# Обещают показать 50 вопросов, а показывают лишь 7

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, метки, вопросы, дизайн

По данной метке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=50

Существует "80 вопросов по метке".

Количество вопросов для отображения на странице установлено в 50 шт.

На рисунке же видно, что отображается лишь 7 вопросов, вместо 50. Причём еще предлагается перейти на страницу номер 2, хотя по логике все вопросы должны уместиться на одной странице (так как с учётом игнорируемых меток, под условие для отображения попадают вопросы в количестве меньшим чем 50).

Отсюда вопрос: это ошибка в вычислении (отображении) или так задумано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 9):

Так задумано. Фильтры по меткам применяются на стороне клиента, т.е. сервер передаёт 50 нефильтрованных вопросов, и потом набольшой скрипт (jQuery) прячет ненужные.

И причина в основном - большой траффик английского сайта Stack Overflow. Проще сформировать страницу для метки и посылать её всем (такие страницы кэшируются), чем формировать индивидуально для каждого.

Comment: Это да, но, по идее, можно было бы сноску какую-нибудь сделать, мол "количество вопросов вычисляется без учёта ваших настроек по меткам" или что-то подобное.